# Entity Framework Core increment integer

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I'm looking for the EF Core C# equivalent of the following SQL statement:

```
UPDATE TheTable 
SET RevisionId = RevisionId + 1 
WHERE notPk = @someValue
```

The solution should not be susceptible to race conditions.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, not a code translation service. Try to translate the code yourself first, then come to us when you are stuck, making sure to show us what you have tried and create a [mre].

Comment: There isn't one. `ExecuteInterpolated` it

Comment: EF Core is an Object-Relational-Mapper, not an embedded SQL library. LINQ isn't a SQL replacement, it's a language that runs on top of the ORM. What objects are involved in the statement you posted?

Comment: I think this is a reasonable question to ask, not great, but OK. The problem is the atomicity of the update. There isn't really a great way to do this safely outside the database so you really just have to execute raw SQL over your connection.

Comment: Hey @DavidG, waiting for 100K hit :) Congrats in advance in case I miss it.

Answer (score 7):

The existing answer from @TomTom was correct at the time, but is now outdated. EF Core 7+ allows you to send bulk updates without first loading an entity.

Using your example:

```
await dbContext.TableItems
  .Where(ti => ti.notPk == someValue)
  .ExecuteUpdateAsync(s =>
    s.SetProperty(ti => ti.RevisionId, ti => ti.RevisionId + 1)
      .SetProperty(ti => ti.AnotherValue, ti => ti.AnotherValue + 1)
  );
```

I added another property to demonstrate how the `SetProperty` invocations are chained together.
More info can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew

Answer (score 3):

Not using EF (Core or not).

Simple like that.

Standard EF has no method to issue this SQL, it requires a load,increment,save.

This automatically makes is prone to race conditions in one way or the other (you can use a version field to catch them and throw an error).

You run literally head straight into a design limitation of an object/relational mapper. They handle 90% of the cases effectively....

What you CAN do is issue this SQL manually - there are various ways to execute custom SQL VIA EfCore. That is what you can do with the other 10%.

There may be third party extensions allowing to generate an Update via EfCore. I.e. https://entityframework-extensions.net/update-from-query - they can do that.

Comment: You can though, using concurrency stamps (though not literally the `SET foo = foo + 1`). Whether you want to is the next question.

Comment: @CodeCaster or by using an explicit transaction. In both cases, it's similar to killing a fly with a cannon.

Comment: Both are not really the same though, and may lead to issues down the road. I generally would do that using above extensions.

Comment: does the extension also allow incrementing? I just saw replacing values